# Android Studio 3.0.1 Emulator Not Loading

Tags: android-emulator

my emulator stopped working after the most recent update. I am currently using the HAX module to run the emulator.

I cannot seem to find the updater for the Intel module (forgive me, I recently started using Android Studio).

Below is the event log which appears when I try to load the emulator:

```
23/02/2018
21:28   Platform and Plugin Updates: The following components are ready to update: Android Emulator, Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image

21:28   Gradle sync started

21:30   Project setup started

21:38   Gradle sync finished in 9m 17s 764ms

21:38   Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

21:38   Gradle build finished in 15s 456ms

21:41   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

21:41   * daemon started successfully

21:41   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

21:41   Emulator: Incompatible HAX module version 3,requires minimum version 4

21:41   Emulator: No accelerator found.

21:41   Emulator: failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument

21:41   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

21:41   Gradle build finished in 5s 978ms
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated! Also, if you find any more problems which could cause further issues to my program, please do notify me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem. I went to the Intel site (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm) and downloaded the latest version of HAXM. I then installed it, and the problem went away!

Comment: It worked! Thanks, dude. I could not update the emulator because I was using the latest version. However, it turns out that I was missing a few files which caused the emulator to not load.